# DDX_Text with DBTIMESTAMP variable, which library do I need to reference?

Tags: c++, mfc, oledb

I want to use DDX_Text with a member variable of type DBTIMESTAMP:

```
class CSerialView : public CFormView
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CSerialView)
    //.....
public:
    DBTIMESTAMP m_ProductionDate; // read from OLEDB consumer class
    //.....
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    //......
}
void CSerialView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CFormView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_PRODUCTIONDATE, m_ProductionDate);
}
```

Compiling is fine, the used syntax of `DDX_Text` is listed in Intellisense, so it appears that Microsoft defined this function somewhere, however the linker bails out with error LNK2019. See attached picture.

[image]

Build output as listed here:

```
1>SerialView.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __stdcall DDX_Text(class CDataExchange *,int,struct tagDBTIMESTAMP &)" (?DDX_Text@@YGXPAVCDataExchange@@HAAUtagDBTIMESTAMP@@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall CSerialView::DoDataExchange(class CDataExchange *)" (?DoDataExchange@CSerialView@@MAEXPAVCDataExchange@@@Z)
1>c:\dev\projects\HCPSOrders\Debug\HCPSOrdersApp.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I am not looking for an explanation of LNK2019 nor LNK1120, I know their meaning. I want to solve this particular error instance: so which reference(s) am I missing?

Comment: What makes you think that structure is supported by [`DDX_Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1xttfdt.aspx)? How would you expect it to work? Do you even know the purpose of the [`DDX_Text`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1xttfdt.aspx) function?

Comment: Yes, I did. The particular overload is not even listed there, though there is one using COleDateTime. Maybe i should go with that one because it can be constructed from DBTIMESTAMP.

Comment: Yes, I know very well what the purpose of DDX_Text is. There is no need to lecture me on that topic or attempt to belittle me.
One more thing, the overload that I want to use is suggested by Intellisense, so maybe it is not so far fetched to think it is supported.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound condescending or rude or anything, I'm a little grumpy today. But the reason that Intellisense says it's okay is because of that `COleDataTime` overload, and that a `COleDataTime` implicitly can be constructed from a `DBTIMESTAMP` (the [`COleDateTime` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yy4h318.aspx) isn't marked `explicit`). You might want to use that class instead.

Comment: I think I will try it using COleDateTime. I still think it is funny that the overload I intended to use is listed explicitly if the function is really not supported.

Comment: What version of VS do you have? In VS2015 I see 17 overloads for `DDX_Text`, none of them include `DBTIMESTAMP`, this fits with `DDX_Text` header file. Also, what do you see in the header file? (it should be called "afxdd_.h")

Comment: I use VS2012 professional. As you can see in the screenshot attached to the question, there are 21 overloads, intended overload being the first. I saw just now it is declared in afxdd_.h as void AFXAPI DDX_Text(CDataExchange* pDX, int nIDC, COleDateTime& value); When I use "goto declaration" in the context menu it takes me to this entry. Apparently Intellisense lists it because COleDateTime can be implicitly constructed  from DBTIMESTAMP. Maybe this is a feature that can be disabled. I will have to look into that. This also answers my question, there is no such explicit overload.

Answer (score -1):

This solved the problem for me:

```
DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_PRODUCTIONDATE, COleDateTime(m_ProductionDate));
```

Comment: Probably not a good idea at all, since the `DDX_Text` takes the third argument by non-const reference, and you construct a temporary object that will be destructed once the `DDX_Text` function returns. Using a reference to a destructed object leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: After the function call returns I will not using the reference anymore. As the data is only meant to be read-only, this is not a problem. My code executes conditionally on pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate == false. You are right that there would be a problem if i wanted to update m_ProductionDate from my CFormView class. The updated object would be destroyed.